# What is the best way to use multiple Themes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm working on a Project using AngularJS, UI Bootstrap, and Sass. Now we want to offer different Themes to the user. I already implemented applying different Backgrounds using `angular.element().css()`. But to change the color of different elements over different sites this doesn't seem the right approach for me. I was thinking of generating different CSS files (`main_dark.css`, `main_light.css`, ...) and loading them with `ng-href`. That way I could separate the Design part from the Development part, but I ran into some problems with that like flashing screens or some dropdowns not working anymore.

Now I want to know if I'm on the right track or if there are better ways to do Themes in AngularJS

Comment: Try separating Layout part with Theme part. I.e. the CSS will be separated into 2 files.  Layout.css - it will always applies and you have theme files for different themes ( Such as red.css, green.css, blue.css etc). These files should contain only color styles (such as backgrounds, borders etc). Insert new css file after the old file upon insert remove the old style. Just an Idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you development in sass they best way is to create main class to body eg.

as a main parent then styling children under this class or you can use https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles but here you nedd to change state to apply new stylesheet